# How do i get n-2 and n+3 elements having the current index and the max items?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So for example if i already know I'm at the position 30 and i know i have 30 elements in total, i need a function that returns an array or object with the prev. 2 elements (29,28) and the next 3 elements (1,2,3), something like this:

http://jsbin.com/ohazag/5/edit (but sadly that it's not working for some conditions).

Is there a better way to do this with javascript or even better a jquery function i probably don't know about? I'm sure I'm missing some cool technique here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a kind of clunky solution based on dmm79's example:

```
var maxPages = 38;
var currentPage = 37;
var pagesToCacheLeft = 2;
var pagesToCacheRight = 3;
var next, prev;

function getPagestoCache(current,max) {
   var intArrayPrev = [];
   var intArrayNext = [];    

   for(var i = 1; i < pagesToCacheLeft + 1; i++)
   {
     var prev = current - i;
     if(prev < 1)
     {
       prev = max + prev;
     }
     console.log(prev);
     intArrayPrev[i-1] = prev;
   }
   for(var j = 1; j < pagesToCacheRight + 1; j++)
   {
     var next = current + j;
     if(next > max)
   {
     next = next % max;
   }
   console.log(next);
   intArrayNext[j - 1] = next;
}

return (intArrayPrev.length && intArrayNext.length) ?  intArrayNext.concat(intArrayPrev):false;
}


var arrPagestoCache = getPagestoCache(currentPage,maxPages);

for (var i=0;i<arrPagestoCache.length;i++){
  console.log("Cache Page->"+arrPagestoCache[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Alexey for fixing up the code, this one is working flawlessly :)

Answer (score 3):

so basically you have an array of x elements and you want the elements [x-2, x+3] !?
my implementation would be straight forward and i am not sure if that is exactly what you need, but i will try to adjust it if you need something else ;)

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
var o_left = 2;  //offset to the left
var x = 5;     //current index
var o_right = 3;  //offset to the right
var arrs = new Array(); //the new array
for (var i = x - o_left; i <= x + o_right; i++) {
  if (i == x)
    continue;
  arrs.push(arr[(i + arr.length) % arr.length]);
}
```

The key in this solution is the % operator which returns the rest of an integer division e.g. 10 % 3 = 1. This means that if the index gets to high, over the end of the array, it starts over from 0.

Comment: I'm not really sure how function should work when we set current index as 1 and left offset begger then index, for example 3, but your solution doesn't give numbers from end of array. Nevertheless, I like you solution for being so compact.

Comment: For example if x = 1 and o_left = 3 I think that it should return 6,7,1 ...[all others depend on o_right], but it returns 1...[all others depend on o_right]

Comment: Yeah, now it works better for me, you already received my vote up. Thanks again.

Comment: I should have indicated that the current item (x in this example) should not be returned in the final array, anyway, i think this is the most elegant and understable solution of all, thanks for the detailed % operator explanation.

Comment: The code in the example (x=5) gives me [4, 5, 7, 1, 2], here: http://jsbin.com/ekunuw/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

The simplest possible solution is to concatenate the array with itself three times and then slice what you need from the bigger array. This costs additional memory, but for arrays < 1000 elements that doesn't matter.

```
vslice = function(a, index, before, after) {
    return [].concat(a, a, a).slice(
        index + a.length - before,
        index + a.length + after + 1
    )
}

vslice([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 1, 2, 3)  // [9,0,1,2,3,4]
vslice([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 9, 2, 3)  // [7,8,9,0,1,2]
vslice([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 5, 2, 3)  // [3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

An illustration for those who don't get it:

```
slice [0,1,2,3], index 1, 2 before, 3 after

-----------
| 0 1 2 3 |
-----------
    ^

1. repeat the array three times

---------------------------
| 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 |
---------------------------

2. add array.length (=4) to the index

---------------------------
| 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 |
---------------------------
    ^       ^
    |_______^


3. subtract "before" (=2) from and add "after" (=3) to the index

---------------------------
| 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 |
---------------------------
        ^   ^     ^
       -2        +3

4. slice between new indexes

---------------
| 3 0 1 2 3 0 |
---------------
```

Comment: I honestly don't understand this code, but thanks a lot for taking the time to write a solution :)

Comment: @dmm79: added an illustration

Comment: Thanks, now i see what you did there, great hack :)